# Pasar datos de un input a un array

Tags: javascript, input

Quería preguntar como puedo pasar los datos de un **input type = number** a un array.

Quería pasar números del input a un array para que dentro se ese array se ordenaran de mayor a menor y después escribirlos en la pantalla , pero me quede estancado al no saber como pasar los numeros al array.
Intente con pasar los numeros usando un .value , pero supongo que lo escribi de forma incorrecta ya que no guardaba los numeros en un array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

¡Hola! Trataré de explicarte cómo funcionan los métodos `push()` y `sort()` con un ejemplo práctico.

1.- Empezaremos con la interfaz de tu aplicación:

```
<input id="inputNumber" type="number" placeholder="Igrese un numero">

<button id="save">Guardar</button>
<button id="ordenar">Oredenar</button>

<div id="mostrar-list-numbers"></div>
```

2.- En la estructura anterior, tenemos un elemento input de tipo number, 2 botones: uno de guardar y el otro de ordenar, y por último un div donde mostraremos los elementos de nuestro arreglo. Nota que cada uno de ellos tiene un ID para poder manipularlos con javascript.

3.- Ahora vamos con javascript: almacenamos en constantes los elementos de nuestra estructura anterior, para tenerlos listos cuando querramos utilizarlos:

```
const btnSave = document.querySelector('#save');

const btnOrdenar = document.querySelector('#ordenar');

const inputNumber = document.querySelector('#inputNumber');

const $listNumbers = document.querySelector('#mostrar-list-numbers');

let arrayNumbers = [];
```

4.- Empecemos con la función de guardar elementos en un arreglo y aquí veremos cómo funciona `push()`

5.- A nuestro **botón de guardar** le agregamos un evento de tipo **click**, recuerda que este botón ya lo tenemos almacenado en una constante:

```
btnSave.addEventListener('click', function(){
   
})
```

6.- Dentro de este evento extraeremos el valor del **input**, lo agregaremos a nuestro **array** y lo mostraremos en el **div** que hemos creado anteriormente:

```
btnSave.addEventListener('click', function(){
       arrayNumbers.push(inputNumber.value);
       $listNumbers.innerHTML = arrayNumbers;
    })
```

7.- Ahora vamos con nuestro botón de **ordenar** que es el más interesante, de igual manera que en el anterior le agregamos un evento de tipo click a este botón:

```
btnOrdenar.addEventListener('click', function(){
  
})
```

8.- Aquí veremos cómo funciona el método `sort()`. Lo que vamos a hacer es ordenar los elementos y mostrarlos en el div.

```
btnOrdenar.addEventListener('click', function(){
  $listNumbers.innerHTML = arrayNumbers.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
  }); 
})
```

9.- Te muestro un ejemplo:

```js
const btnSave = document.querySelector('#save');

const btnOrdenar = document.querySelector('#ordenar');

const inputNumber = document.querySelector('#inputNumber');

const $listNumbers = document.querySelector('#mostrar-list-numbers');

const arrayNumbers = [];


btnSave.addEventListener('click', function(){
   arrayNumbers.push(inputNumber.value);
  $listNumbers.innerHTML = arrayNumbers;
})

btnOrdenar.addEventListener('click', function(){
  $listNumbers.innerHTML = arrayNumbers.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b;
  }); 
})
```

```html
<input id="inputNumber" type="number" placeholder="Igrese un número">

<button id="save">Guardar</button>
<button id="ordenar">Ordenar</button>

<div id="mostrar-list-numbers"></div>
```

**Te dejo la documentación para que profundices más en el tema:**

[Método sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

[Método push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push)

[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Me gustaría hacer dos aclaraciones. En este caso, a la función `sort` no hace falta pasarle ninguna `function`; al tratarse de `number` podemos usar la ordenación por defecto. `arrayNumbers.sort()` hace exactamente lo mismo. Segundo, `sort` es una función que no sigue con el paradigma funcional, es decir, es una función que muta el `array`, por lo qe sería más correcto `[...arrayNumbers].sort()` para mantener el `array` original si fuera necesario.

Comment: Hola @VRoxa, te invito a que realices pruebas con **sort()**, incluso en la documentacion de **MDN** muestra un ejemplo del resultado esperado cuando utilizas **sort()** sin función de comparación, te invita a que des un vistazo a la documentacion que deje en mi respuesta. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: tienes razón, my bad.

Comment: @VRoxa En lo que si concuerdo contigo, es que **sort()** muta el arreglo, si tu fuiste el del voto en contra, deberias de consideralo. PD: Gracias por las ediciones tengo muy mala ortografía. Saludos.

Comment: No, no he sido yo. No considero que tu respuesta merezca un voto negativo.